# There is an if-else, is there a Neither Nor statement?

Tags: c++

Is there a `neither A nor B` syntax?

Comment: Though it seems to make sense in English it is hard to really tell as English is such an imprecise language. Do you have a mathematical definition of the functionality you want. If you can define this 'neither' and 'nor' in terms of true and false then the rest should be trivial.

Comment: Intuitively that would translate to `neither(x) { /* doesn't happen */ } nor(y) { /* doesn't happen */ }` for me... Probably not what you intended.

Comment: actually, as Rekreativc mentions, the comparable feature to "Neither Nor' Isn't "if-else" is "and" (or "both-and" if you prefer) or "or" ("either-or") so you're really looking for a logical operator not a statement keyword...

Answer (score 63, accepted):

While there isn't a built-in syntax to do this, I'd suggest you take a look at the [list of supported logical operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_logical_operators#Logical_operators) and then carefully study [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws). Sufficient knowledge in these two fields will allow you to write any logical statement in *if–else if* syntax.

**EDIT:** To completely answer your question (although this has been done already in other answers), you could write a neither–nor statement like this:

```
if (!A && !B) { DoStuff(); }
```

Comment: +1 for De Morgan's law, something every programmer should know.

Comment: Exactly, you don't need more than (`&&`, `~`) OR (`||`, `~`) to represent any logical connection.

Comment: Thanks for that - I knew the laws, but didn't know they were named after anybody :-)

Comment: Just wanted to add that you can change that operator to `if (!(A || B)) { DoStuff(); }` and it will work exactly the same.

Answer (score 105):

Oh ... you wanted the "ain't" keyword?

> **VB adds Ain't Keyword**
>
> (Newswire 8-19-2004)
>
> Microsoft has announced that Visual
>   Basic will add the "Ain't" keyword to
>   the language. According to a source on
>   the VB.NET team "With VB, we want the
>   language to work the way you think.
>   Extensive usability studies have
>   demonstrated to us the benifit of
>   adding Ain't to the language."
>
> Addition of the keyword would allow
>   such syntax as
>
> ```
> If ThisThing Ain't Nothing Then
> ```
>
> According the source "We're just
>   trying to keep up with advances in the
>   English language which, as you know,
>   is changing almost as fast as
>   technology itself." The VB team
>   believes that [ain't is poised to
>   finally be a fully supported keyword
>   in the English language](http://www.alphadictionary.com/articles/drgw003.html), and they
>   feel that if they don't include the
>   keyword in this release, they may fall
>   well behind English before their next
>   chance to update VB. However, hotly
>   debated is what "Ain't" should equate
>   to. In it's most popular form, the
>   above line of code would translate to:
>
> ```
> If ThisThing Is Nothing Then
> ```
>
> However, everyone's 2nd grade english
>   teacher has made it clear that "Ain't
>   Nothing" actually means "Is
>   Something", as it's a double-negative.
>   Meaning the correct equivelant would
>   be
>
> ```
> If ThisThing IsNot Nothing Then
> ```
>
> Microsoft is in no hurry to rush
>   through this decision, state sources,
>   "Look, between VB.NET Beta 1 and Beta
>   2, we had to [change the definition of 'true'](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=21414). We don't want to go
>   through that again."
>
> However language purists declare that
>   this whole approach is misguided,
>   noting that "Ain't" is a contraction
>   for "am not", and saying "If ThisThing
>   Am Not Nothing" is just poor grammar.
>   Better alternatives, they say, would
>   include resurecting i'n't, as in "If
>   ThisThing I'n't Nothing". But even
>   this may not be far enough states
>   linguist Jacque Leblanc, "I insist
>   that the perpetuation of the double
>   negative is the root cause of this
>   issue, but as of yet, no one is really
>   willing to discuss the obvious
>   elephant in the room. The true
>   solution would be to allow 'If
>   ThisItem Is Something Then.'"
>
> Microsoft is also reported to be
>   experimenting with "AsIf", "Maybe",
>   and "Totally". In addition, "Catch"
>   will likely be replaced with "Doh!",
>   and "Finally" will be replaced with
>   "Whatever".

source:     http://web.archive.org/web/20050308014055/http://ea.3leaf.com/2004/08/vb_adds_aint_ke.html

Comment: They really wrote "_In **it's** most popular form_" instead of [its](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/its#Pronoun) when the topic is language (with apostrophes).

Answer (score 15):

To encode "if neither A nor B":

```
if (!A && !B) { ... } //if (not A) and (not B)
```

or:

```
if (!(A || B)) { ... } //if not (A or B)
```

Comment: AKA De Morgan's law in the other answer.

Answer (score 14):

Here you go:

```
class neither_t
{
    bool lhv;
    neither_t(bool lhv): lhv(lhv) {}
public:
    bool nor(bool rhv) const
    {
        return !lhv && !rhv;
    }
    friend neither_t neither(bool lhv);
};

neither_t neither(bool lhv)
{
    return neither_t(lhv);
}

#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    int x = 3;
    if (neither(x == 1).nor(x == 2)) {
        puts("OK");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you didn't misname it either. that's a misuse in american english that bugs me.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't.

Answer (score 3):

do you mean `unless` from perl?

```
$a = 12;
unless($a >= 0) {
  print "a is negative\n";
} elsif ($a == 0) {
  print "a is equal to 0\n";  
} else {
  print "a is positive\n";  
}
# it prints: a is positive
```

Strangely there is no `else unless`, only (the equivalent of) `else if`.

Answer (score 1):

no. You can achieve the same using `if` in conjunction with `!` (not), `&&` (and) and `||` (or)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( x == 1 )
{ // do this }

else if ( x == 2 )
{ // do this }

else { // do this if it's neither 2 nor 1 }
```

the last else is the same as:

```
if ( x != 1 && x != 2 ) { // do something }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The && and || operators in C do perform flow control, and all expressions are statements, so && and || form flow control statements. The terms of the expression are evaluated until its value is known, so && will execute  a series of true expressions and || will execute a series of false expressions. As || (OR) keeps going as long as its arguments are false (NOT), it can be called a neither-nor statement.

```
bool a = fun1(), b = fun2();
a || b || ( cerr << "neither A nor B is true" << endl );
!a && !b && ( cerr << "De Morgan says neither A nor B is true" << endl );
```

"But," you say, "that's not really a flow control statement. It only affects flow control *within* one statement." Fair nuff. The `throw` operator is actually also an expression with type `void`. So we can extend this, erm, style to cover blocks of several lines.

```
try {
    a || b || ( throw logic_error( "neither a nor b is true" ), false );
} catch( logic_error &exc ) {
    cerr << exc.what() << endl;
    cerr << "now with added madness!" << endl;
}
```

I hope that's what you wanted…

Answer (score 0):

Ruby does have some of this kind of syntactic sugar:

- *unless* is the equivalent of *if !*
- *collection.empty?* can be used as the equivalent of *!collection.any?*

Comment: I really miss the unless keyword, surprised python doesn't have it, the way ternaries are eschewed by the BDFL.